# How to track down where a 404 error in console is coming from

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, google-chrome-devtools, shopify

I'm cleaning up a Shopify and there's several 404 messages coming from the console. It's obvious that a script is trying to load content (PNG images) that no longer exist on the server.

How can I track down what script these are coming from? In the console it states that it's coming from a linked copy of minified jquery, plain ol jquery.min.js - it will link a specific line in the code as well but this line has nothing relevant to the issue.

I've been trying to research my way into solving where this comes from for awhile now - I wasn't able to find another question on StackOverflow quite like this. For reference, the page I'm looking at is https://www.bearbuttteam.com/collections/double-hammies/products/bear-butt-double-hammock where there are many errors in the console relating to images.

I've looked through all the files used in the site and none of them had explicit filenames for the errors that are coming up.. I can see that these are taking some time in the Network panel and I would love to clean them up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing `jquery.js` twice. Remove the jquery.min.js you're calling from Google server. It's an older version. Shopify is already adding a latest jquery file.

Refer below image

[image]

Comment: while that helped, the images are still showing up as 404 errors in the console. do you know of a way i can track where these are coming from? the link to the script line doesn't seem to be accurate

Comment: Images are missing from "Files" section in you Shopify store. Check under `Settings -> Files` in your admin panel.

Comment: yeah they're definitely not there - they've been removed, but still show up in the console area. i'm wondering what i can do to stop them from trying to load. basically i want to remove the 'dead link' that's causing them to still show up in console

Comment: They are being called in the inline styles on the page.

Comment: it has to be put there by a script though... i don't understand how because i can't find any instances of those PNG files in any .liquid or asset folders

Comment: The elements are being called directly from HTML. It has to be in `.liquid`. Go line by line through the entire liquid code that generates that product page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137646/discussion-between-hymnz-and-fuccboi).